# How do I return response for a request in plain text from drupal 7?

Tags: php, drupal-7

I have drupal 7 configured on my system. By default it returns response in json format.

```
if ($op == 'condition1') {
    $output = 'output1';
    return $output;     
}
if ($op == 'condition2') { 
    $output = 'output2';  
    return (object)$output;
}
```

currently ,

`condition 1` gives response as

```
[
"output1"
];
```

`condtion 2` gives response as

```
[
"scaler" : "output2";
]
```

But I need response a simply as plain text 
eg
output

I dont know what settings to change.

The available response formatters  are bencode, json, jsonp, php, xml.

Thanks.